# Trying to run scrapy shell command for a .gg website, but returns an empty bracket

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm tyring to run command response.css(".hero-name::text").extract()  in the scrapy shell  but an empty bracket is returned.

steps I've taken

```
scrapy shell 'https://msf.gg/characters'
>>> response.css(".hero-name::text").extract()
```

[] an empty bracket is returned.
I've as well tried to run the xpath and the same result

```
>>> response.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/ul/li[1]/div[3]/h4/text()").extract()
```

[]

Comment: If you check view-source:https://msf.gg/characters these values are not present so I guess you need to check API / JS calls from where these values are coming.
I checked and there is one js from these are coming https://msf.gg/static/js/app.b43c55bc722bb82280bd.js So you need to work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all,**

you should do just `scrapy shell 'https://msf.gg/characters'` instead of doing it scrapy shell twice.

**Secondly,**

it is a dynamic-rendered page i.e. JS-rendered pages;

therefore scrapy is unable to locate those elements, you could do `view(response)` to see; (this is basically what scrapy see)

**One solution** would be to use [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) or [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback.  I'm not sure if I'm following what you mean by doing scrappy shell twice.  I believe I did it only one time,  I ran scrapy shell 'URL' and then ran the command.  Also I will do some research on requests-html and see what I come up with.  Thanks for your help